# Minimum and maximum coordinates of a polygon in Earth engine

Tags: polygon, google-earth-engine, coordinates, boundaries

I have a Fusion table having shape-files of various districts of India and I am using this fusion table in Earth Engine code.

```
var district = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1PA2zwArj8EsplrX9eMxJ2H_TICyyx855KPnbJhC1','geometry')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('name','Begusarai'));

var district_image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
    .filterBounds(district)
    .filterDate('2018-03-01','2018-05-01')
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',5))
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .map(maskClouds)
    .median();
```

Then I perform some classification on the given image and export the classified image to my drive
'input' variable is having that classified image..

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: input.clip(district),
  description: 'begusarai2018',
  scale: 30,
  region: district
});
```

I now want to get the maximum and minimum coordinates (Latitude and Longitude) of these districts.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer for my question today as:

```
var district = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1PA2zwArj8EsplrX9eMxJ2H_TICyyx855KPnbJhC1','geometry')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('name','Begusarai'));

var boundbox = district.geometry().bounds();
Map.centerObject(bbox); Map.addLayer(bbox); Map.addLayer(geometry, {color: 'red'});
print(district);

// return the list of coordinates
var listCoords = ee.Array.cat(boundbox.coordinates(), 1); 

// get the X and Y -coordinates
var xCoords = listCoords.slice(1, 0, 1);
var yCoords = listCoords.slice(1, 1, 2);

// reduce the arrays to find the max (or min) value
var xMin = xCoords.reduce('min', [0]).get([0,0]); print('xMin',xMin);
var xMax = xCoords.reduce('max', [0]).get([0,0]); print('xMax',xMax);
var yMin = yCoords.reduce('min', [0]).get([0,0]); print('yMin',yMin);
var yMax = yCoords.reduce('max', [0]).get([0,0]); print('yMax',yMax);
```

and it works well for my problem

Comment: can I get those min max values in different coordinate systems. what If i'd like the min and max value in meter using ESPG:3857?